# How to select Echarts.graph highlighting by clicking

Tags: graph, highlight, echarts

I have an Echarts graph (similar to a network graph), which has many nodes and edges. When I put the mouse on a node, the adjacent edges and nodes will be highlighted, but how can I move the mouse The highlighting of these nodes is still maintained after leaving. In other words, I want to trigger and cancel the highlighting by clicking, rather than hovering over the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

in my case using `click`, `mouseout`, `highlight` event worked.

I can't find way to avoid default mouse hover event. so set `click` and `mouseout` event callback.

When `click` event occur, save the node 'dataIndex'. And when `mouseout` event occur, emit 'highlight' event with 'dataIndex' (use `dispatchAction` api)

Answer (score -1):

In your tooltip chart options, add the option trigger:

```
tooltip : {
  triggerOn : 'click'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it just for tooltip, I want to keep the highlight of all edge of a node after I clicked a node.